# Replace nested ForEach with Select if applicable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

Is it possible to replace method `ForEach()` usage with `Select()` or something else to write next code in one string with nested extension methods? OR maybe there are another ways to improve the algorithm?

```
var list = new List<IStatementParser>();

System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll")
    .ForEach(f => System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(f)
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .ForEach(t => list.Add((IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(t))));

return list.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.GetType());
```

It loads all classes  from assemblies in `path` that implements `IFoo` and adds them to `Dictionary<string, Type>` where string is `IFoo.Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var foos =
    from dllFile in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll")
    from type in Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile).GetTypes()
    where !type.IsInterface && typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select (IFoo) Activator.CreateInstance(type);

return foos.ToDictionary(foo => foo.Name, foo => foo.GetType());
```

Comment: You need a foo => foo.GetType() parameter as the value delegate in the ToDictionary call. Otherwise, an excellent answer.

Comment: I need only to clarify usage of 'let' above and I'm ready to accept your answer. And btw, I don't need Dictionary<string, IFoo>, I need Dictionary<string, Type> where Type = IFoo (I edited initial post) -- because this dictionary will be used by FooFactory to create an instance of IFoo by request, that may doesn't happen at all, in current session.

Comment: Edited to include the .GetType() call. The let clause in @Pavel's answer is a style thing - you don't need to have it, but he may perceive it as more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any need for an intermediate `List` here at all - you can just do this:

```
return (from dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll")
        let asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll)
        from t in asm.GetTypes()
        where !t.IsInterface && typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t)
        select (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(t)
       ).ToDictionary(foo => foo.Name, foo => foo.GetType())
```

By the way, you might also want to check whether a type is `abstract` before trying to instantiate it.

Comment: Could you please describe what for do you use 'let'? Bryan Watts below doesn't

Comment: It's a convenience/readability thing, not strictly necessary.